# z3 variable types switching

Tags: python, python-3.x, z3, z3py

While playing with Z3, I've discovered problems when variables change types. I have been able to get `Int` to play nice with `Real`. I've also gotten `Int` to convert to `BitVec` and back. However, it appears that once I hit a threshold of converting between `Int` and `BitVec`, the z3 solver goes off the tracks and doesn't return.

An example of my solver state looks like this:

```
[271733878 == a,
562383102 == b,
4023233417 == c,
1732584193 == d,
e ==
BV2Int(int2bv(d) ^
    int2bv(BV2Int(int2bv(b) &
                  int2bv(BV2Int(int2bv(c) ^
                                int2bv(a)))))),
f == e,
305419896 == g]
```

That actually works fine. However, if I do one more int2bv conversion Z3 will never return and I have to kill python. Again, the problem being these variables are actually very volatile as far as what types they might take on. I had considered only using BitVec, but that causes problems if I want to add a BitVec and a Real together.

Am I trying to use Z3 for something it's not made for? Is there any way to salvage using Z3 for this type of a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular tuning for int2bv and bv2int conversions, so you are often left with the fallback mechanism that bit-blasts and then engages in an elaborate combination of bit-vector and arithmetical reasoning. I would suggest that you try to delay conversions from bit-vectors to integers until a last resort in your front-end. In the example, there is no particular reason to keep converting the intermediary bit-vectors to integers. Z3 does not detect this redundancy. It also has to take into account that integer to bit-vector conversion is potentially lossy because it is modulo a bit-width.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll definitely delay the conversions as you mentioned. However, I also do hope that more effort will be placed into those conversions at some point as I feel it's likely the need for a more efficient approach to conversions (or even implicit conversions between the two) will be more utilized in the future.

Comment: Just out of interest, do you have an application that actually requires the conversion between the two theories, or are you converting between them just for convenience and all could be done exclusively in one of the theories?